# Object passed as an parameter doesn't create multiple instance

Tags: java, multithreading, static, multiple-instances, pass-by-value

I am dealing with Multi Threading in my program. 
The object is being passed as a value. However I have noticed that the object when passed as a parameter, doesn't create another instance.

I am using multi threading where in the called method I am changing value of an variable (belongs to the object passed as an argument), and in the calling method also the variable changes.

```
Class_1
{
  Public Static void main()
  {
    SomeObject obj=new SomeObject();
    Class_2 class_2=new Class_2();
    obj.setVar1(someValue) 
    class_2.method_2(obj)
    thread.sleep(5000)   // --> Till then the method_2() gets executed
    system.out.println(obj.getVar1)  // --> Also prints someAnotherValue (SHOULD PRINT someValue)
  }
}

Class_2
{
  method_2(SomeObject obj)  // --> non static method
  {
    obj.setVar1(someAnotherValue)
    system.out.println(obj.getVar1)  // --> Print someAnotherValue
  }
}
```

I have been thinking that the objects when passed as a parameter creates another instance. 
I want my object to create another instance when passed. Is it possible?

I can give explain it a bit more if required.

UPDATE:

Sample Bean Class

```
public class IngestionBean {
    private String stageDDL;

    public String getStageDDL() {
        return stageDDL;
    }

    public void setStageDDL(String stageDDL) {
        this.stageDDL = stageDDL;
    }
}
```

ArchiveMain class

Here the data inside for loop goes into threading.

```
public class ArchiveMain
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
    IngestionBean ingestionBean = new IngestionBean();
    ArchivingData archivingData;

    //..

    //----- ArchivingData is threaded class, will be called multiple times
    //----- Assume dataFile.length = 2
    for (int i = 0; i < dataFile.length; i++)
    {
        archivingData = new ArchivingData(ingestionBean, dataFile[i], ddlFile[i], i);
        archivingData.start();
    }

    //..    
    }
}
```

ArchivingData class

for every thread value of stageDDL is being changed -- inside run()

```
public class ArchivingData implements Runnable
{
    private HiveDao hiveDao = new HiveDao();
    private IngestionBean ingestionBean = new IngestionBean();
    public ArchivingData(IngestionBean ingestionBean, String dataFile, String ddlFile, Integer i)
    {
    this.ingestionBean = ingestionBean;
    this.dataFile = dataFile;
    this.ddlFile = ddlFile;
    }

    public void run()
    {
    //.. 
    String stageTableName = dataFile.replace("-", "_").replace(".", "_");

    //---- Changing the value of stageDDL in IngestionBean class in every new thread
    //---- Second thread is called instantly after the first thread
    ingestionBean.setStageDDL(ddlFilePath.toString());          

    //---- passing ingestionBean object
    Boolean stageTableStatus = hiveDao.createStageTable(ingestionBean, stageTableName, intvalue);    

    //..
    }

    public void start() throws InterruptedException
    {
    LOGGER.info("Starting thread for datafile: " + dataFile);
    if (thread == null)
    {
        thread = new Thread(this, dataFile);
        thread.start();
    }
    }
}
```

HiveDao class

Since not much operations are involved, the all the thread reaches createStageTable at the same time
And thread will have the same value of stageDDL (since only one instance of ingestionBean object is created)

```
public class HiveDao
{
    public Boolean createStageTable(IngestionBean ingestionBean)
    {
    //---- Don't receive unique value of stageDDL here
    //---- Always receive the latest value of stageDDL (modified in run() )
    //---- It is not creating another instance of ingestionBean object. Using the same instance created in main()
    statement.executeUpdate(ingestionBean.getStageDDL);     
    }
}
```

I want new instance of ingestionBean object to be created after the object is passed to ArchivingData in for loop. 
Is it possible

Comment: please share actual code

Comment: Although we say that Java is always "pass by value", the values that are passed are actually references to objects, not objects themselves. In some ways, that makes Java behave a little like "pass by reference".  In particular, if you want an extra copy of an object to be created, you'll have to explicitly create it - you can't create copies of objects just by passing them to methods.

Comment: Hi David. Please have a look I have added the actual code. So, inorder to have different value of stageDDL, I would need to createa new object of IngestionBean inside run() ?

Answer (score 4):

Java passes *references* to objects, not objects. If you want another instance, then create one before calling the method.

PS: when you post code, post *real* code, and not code with a language of your imagination. Also respect the Java naming conventions. Also, I don't want to be rude, but multi-threading is a very, very hard topic, and you'd better understand the fundamentals of Java and OO before even thinking about multithreading.

Comment: Agreed. This is my first time in multi-threading. I have added the actual code.

Answer (score -1):

Java passes reference.

Simpliest way is to clone object.. if it makes sense in real implementation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks